# Reinitalize item-controller after route transition

Tags: javascript, ember.js, coffeescript

I am trying to build a series of checkbox to check days of the week, but I can't figure out how to maintain proper presentation state when switching routes.

Since it keeps the previous state (controllers are singleton), I can't figure out what's the best way to reinitialize it every time I transition and also when I try to create a new instance of event.

The setup is the following (coffeescript notation):

an array controller defined as such:

```
ProjectEventsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  itemController: 'project/event'
```

The item controller contains observers that watch changes on checkboxes

```
ProjectEventController = Ember.ObjectController.extend

  mon:true
  tue:true
  wed:true
  thu:true
  fri:true
  sat:true
  sun:true

  _days: []

  eventId: undefined

  eventObserver: (()->

    if !@get('eventId')
      @set 'eventId', @get('event.id')
      @set '_days', @defaultDays

      # if we have a recurrence days, we check the days that are already checked
      # else we check them all
      if @get('event.recurrence') and @get('event.recurrence.days')
        console.log 'existing recurrence', @get('event.recurrence.days')
        (@defaultDays.filter (day)=>
          !@get('event.recurrence.days').contains day
        ).forEach (uncheckedDay)=>
          console.log 'uncheckedDay', uncheckedDay
          @set uncheckedDay.toLowerCase(), false

    if (@get('event.recurrence') and @get('event.recurrence.days') == @defaultDays)
      console.log 'all days checked', @get('event.recurrence.days'), @defaultDays
      @set 'recurrenceEnabled', false
  ).observes('event.id')


  _daysObserver: ((k,v)->
    val = @get v
    key = v.toUpperCase()
    days = @get '_days'
    if val
      if !days.contains key
        days.push key
    else
      days = days.filter (item)->
       item != key

    @set '_days', days
    if @get 'event.recurrence'
      @set 'event.recurrence.days', days.toArray()
    else
      @set 'event.recurrence', Ember.Object.create
        type: 'weekly'
        days: days
        start_hhmm: @defaultHHmm
        duration_seconds: @defaultDuration
  ).observes('mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun')
```

The checkbox is then simple something like this:

```
<div>{{input checked=thu type="checkbox" disabled=recurrenceNotEnabled }} Thu</div>
```

JsBin of this code is at:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/boweze/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to reset the properties on transition from the route.

Check out resetController method on the Route.

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_resetController

Then you could reset the controller's EventId property to undefined from inside the resetController method. That looks like it would do what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .on('init') along with the observers to have the code fire on initialization as well.

Updated JsBin:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/boweze/4/edit